# Issue with updating table data in Swing UI view

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a UI in Netbeans and am having problems getting one of my tables to work. The data in it goes not get updated when I call this method:

```
public void UpdateTable() {
    DefaultTableModel TableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    //(new Object[] { "ID", "Name", "Age" "Sex" "Address" "blah" }, 5)

    TableView.setModel(TableModel);

    for (Patient k : PatientList) {
        String TableID = String.valueOf(k.getAccountNumber());
        String TableName = k.getName();
        String TableAge = String.valueOf(k.getAge());
        String TableAddress = k.getAddress();
        String TableSex = k.getSex();
        String TablePhone = k.getPhone();

        Object[] Col = { "Name", "Code", "age", "blah", "Who", "ghg" };
        Object[] Data = { TableID, TableName, TableAge, TableAddress,
                TableSex, TablePhone };

        TableModel.addRow(Data, Col); //here
        JTableHeader header = TableView.getTableHeader();

        repaint();
    }

    System.out.println("Model Set");
    TableView.setModel(TableModel);
}
```

The error is occurring on the line that I commented and I am totally confused as to how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you need to double post a question, do us all a favor and post the entire question, don't make people go hunting for it.  This question is also out of context. You need to provide a runnable example for us to dignose

Comment: I would suggest the users from the previous thread where on the right track.  Do you NEED to create a new model or are you just trying to update what is already been displayed on the screen?

Comment: Use standard Java naming conventions. Variable names DO NOT start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

One of the ways to create a "empty" table model using `DefaultTableModel` would be to do something like...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                                    new Object[]{"ID", "Name", "Age" "Sex" "Address" "blah"},
                                    0);
```

This is important.  You don't want there to be any existing rows in the model.

There are only two `addRow` methods.

```
Object[] Data = { TableID, TableName, TableAge, TableAddress, TableSex, TablePhone };
model.addRow(data);
```

Get rid of the first `TableView.setModel(TableModel);` and `JTableHeader header = TableView.getTableHeader();` and `repaint();` as they are adding no value

I would strongly suggest you have a read of [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information

Comment: +1, for suggesting to read the API. @user2165938 How do you expect the method to work when it only needs one parameter and you are providing two?